# jhispter custom webflux security exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-security, jhipster, spring-webflux

Does anyone know how to throw custom exception handling in spring webflux security?

Basically if the oauth2 oidc token validations

1. Invalid audience
2. Invalid signature
3. Time expired
4. Invalid issuer
5. Identity status check